# Playback skips and plays frames slowly with new audio?

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio, frame-rate

I have a video in 1080p and inserted audio. When I play this back, the video preview window is lagging and skipping frames. The audio however sounds normal. This problem does not happen when I only play the initial audio.

My computer has not had this problem when I previously replaced the audio in Blender and I tried restarting my computer with the same problems.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have enabled AV Sync in the timeline window (different from VSE window)

[image: AV sync]

This will tell Blender to skip video frames in order to play at the project frame rate.